# What is this noise?

Tags: noise, abs

My car is making an odd noise, which you can hear in [this video](http://youtu.be/mfA1Xz6mUzo).

It only makes the noise as soon as I turn the car on. Can someone let me know what it is?

The ABS light has also come on.

Comment: What is the make, model and year of the vehicle?  Have you had the codes read?

Answer (score 2):

With the limited info available it sounds like the ABS pump running. I can't think of anything else that cycles that fast. Why it would be running at start up I haven't a clue. You could try pulling the ABS fuse and see if the noise stops.

Comment: Agreed with pulling the ABS fuse. I'm betting the pump is stuck in diagnostic mode where it cycles to do a self test, but is failing.